# WP Rest API get translated categories (WPML)

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I'm using Wordpress and the Woocommerce plugin. Further I have WPML Plugin installed for 4 languages. Additionally I'm using an Ionic 2 App, which is connected to the Shop with WP Rest API. I would like now to get the categories in the translated languages in the app. Following is the code to get the categories. I tried to add **/?lang=it** at the and of the string "/wp-json/wc/v1/products/categories" => "/wp-json/wc/v1/products/categories/?lang=it, but I get everytime the english (native) categories. What I did is I tried this on https://resttesttest.com/ and there I'm able to feed the specific languages.

```
 getStoreCategories(params) {
    var service = this;
    let url = service.appConfig.Shop_URL + "/wp-json/wc/v1/products/categories";
    url = this.initUrl(url, params);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      service.http.get(service.initRequest(url, 'get')).catch(err => {
        reject('error');
        return Observable.throw(err);
      }).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        if (data) {
          service.cachedData = data;
          resolve(service.cachedData);
        }
        else {
          reject();
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL would be different for rest API with WPML in case if you are using below structure

Assuming sample product url

if URL structure is `http://yoursite.com/ar/product/product-01`

then your API call would be

```
let url = service.appConfig.Shop_URL + "{lang_code}" + "/wp-json/wc/v1/products/categories";
```

if URL structure is taking language code as `Query string` like  `http://yoursite.com/product/product-01?lang=ar`

then your API call would be

```
let url = service.appConfig.Shop_URL + "/wp-json/wc/v1/products/categories?lang=" + {lang_code};
```

P.S i don't know about the syntax in react but i've given you an idea

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this. I pass the parameter lang in my request as follows:

```
this.myService.getStoreCategories({ page: 1, per_page: 100, lang: 'it' }).then((categories: Array<any>) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multilanguage by the WPML Plugin. You can use the code for multilanguage by filtering the default category response.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_prepare_product_cat', 'change_product_categories_response', 10, 3 );

function change_product_categories_response( $response, $item, $request ) {
global $sitepress;
$lang  = sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['lang'] );

$sitepress->switch_lang( $lang );

return $response;
}
```